# How to group by records in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to use Group By method supported by LINQ.

I have this class

```
public class Attribute
{
  public int Id {get;set;} 

  public string Name {get;set;}

  public string Value {get;set;} 

}
```

I have a service method that will retrive a IList

```
var attributes = _service.GetAll();
Id  Name    Value
7   Color   Black
7   Color   White
220 Size    16
```

Now I have another tow classes

one is

```
public class AttributeResourceModelSubItem
{
   public string Name {get;set;}

   public List<AttributeValueResourceModelSubItem> values { get; set; }
}

public class AttributeValueResourceModelSubItem
{
   public int Id;
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I am trying to loop through the attributes list. and if the attribute id is the same, I wanna insert the records where id = to that id inside the AttributeValueResourceModelSubItem in which id = 1 and Name  will be equal to the attribute value.

This what I got so far.

```
private IList<AttributeResourceModelSubItem> FormatAttributes(IList<Attribute> attributes)
{
    Dictionary<int, Attribute> baseTypes = new Dictionary<int, Attribute>();
    AttributeResourceModelSubItem attributeResourceModelSubItem = null;
    var list = new IList<AttributeResourceModelSubItem>();
    foreach (var item in attributes)
    {
        if (!baseTypes.ContainsKey(item.Id))
        {
            attributeResourceModelSubItem = new AttributeResourceModelSubItem()
            attributeResourceModelSubItem.key = item.Name;
            attributeResourceModelSubItem.values.Add(new AttributeValueResourceModelSubItem()
            {
                id = 1,
                name = item.Value
            });
            list.Add(attributeResourceModelSubItem);
        }
        baseTypes.Add(item.Id, item);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where did `values` in `attributeResourceModelSubItem.values.Add` come from?

Comment: actually i for got to add the values attribute in the AttributeResourceModelSubItem class. I will  modify it.

Comment: `new IList<AttributeResourceModelSubItem>();`?

Comment: Also, you're saying `if (!baseTypes.ContainsKey(item.Id))`, then regardless of the result of that, you're adding an item with that key. That's quite conceivably going to give you a runtime error.

Comment: what is the solution then ?

Comment: All this does is initialise a data structure. Where is the code for GROUP BY? You want someone to just write it for you?

Comment: Using group by is not a mandatory thing, I am asking for any possible method

Comment: For LINQ-ify questions like this, it generally helps to see a working example that doesn't use LINQ. It sounds like you have an idea of what you want, so write it with a `foreach` *so it works*, then show us that. Beyond that, I've posted an answer to the question I *think* you're asking.

Comment: Do you want to group by name and then project id and name? Like attributes.GroupBy(x=>x.Name, x=>new AttributeValueResourceModelSubItem(){Id=x.Id,Name=x.Key}.SelectMany(x=>x.AsEnumerable()).ToList()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty unclear from your example what you're actually trying to do, but this is the gist I get.

```
private IEnumerable<AttributeResourceModelSubItem> FormatAttributes(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
{
    return attributes.GroupBy(c => c.Id)
                     .Select(c => new AttributeResourceModelSubItem()
                                  {
                                      key = c.First().Name,
                                      values = c.Select(x => new AttributeValueResourceModelSubItem()
                                                             {
                                                                 id = 1,
                                                                 name = x.value
                                                             }).ToList();
                                  });
}
```

You should also definitely *not* use the word `Attribute` as a class name. That's already a .NET class.

I'll admit that I don't quite understand the `id = 1` part, but I took that from your code. It also seems odd to group by the `id` then try and take the first `name`, but again that's what you have.

If you do, in fact, want to group by the name and take the `id`, which makes a little more sense, you'll want to swap a couple things around. Admittedly this structure still seems a little odd to me, but hopefully this will get you a couple steps closer to your goal.

```
private IEnumerable<AttributeResourceModelSubItem> FormatAttributes(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes)
{
    return attributes.GroupBy(c => c.name)
                     .Select(c => new AttributeResourceModelSubItem()
                                  {
                                      key = c.Key,
                                      values = c.Select((item, index) => new AttributeValueResourceModelSubItem()
                                                             {
                                                                 id = index + 1,
                                                                 name = item.value
                                                             }).ToList();
                                  });
}
```

I also made your `id = 1` increment starting at one for each element in each `values` list. You might want that to be `item.Id`, or even just your original `1`.

Comment: @Mohammadjouhari did that answer your question?

Comment: @Mohammadjouhari Awesome. Please mark this answer as accepted so it might help users in the future with similar questions.